# Read properties file externally in Spring boot?

Tags: java

I am new to the **Spring Boot**, but has extensive experience traditional `Spring MVC`. In my traditional application, I can read **.properties** file from outside of the application like shown in the below. Can somebody can tell me how to achieve below in **Spring Boot** if possible ?

```
<beans:bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="locations">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>file:///${user.home}/prp/db.properties</beans:value>
            <beans:value>file:///${user.home}/prp/app.properties</beans:value>
         </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: @ Lukas Bradley - already seen this, but not clear. Hence posted the question...

Comment: At class level use this @PropertySource(value={"file:///${user.home}/prp/app.properties"})